# How to aggregate if a condition is met in a transposed dataset?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to figure out how to "aggregate" this transposed dataset. I am not sure if aggregate is the right word because the math is happening across rows. I have a dataframe that looks similar to such:

EDIT: There are multiple cases of the same value in "date." The data is transposed to the person ID. There are also Date1-5 columns as well. The date referenced in the below table is the one i ultimately home to aggregate by for the created NRev1-NRev# values.

| Date | Return1 | Return2 | Return3 | Return4 | Return5 | Rev1 | Rev2 | Rev3 | Rev4 | Rev5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-1 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 100 | 500 | 100 | 200 | 300 |
| 2020-2 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | nan | 200 | 120 | 100 | 200 | nan |
| 2020-3 | 2 | 3 | 7 | 9 | nan | 100 | 0 | 100 | 200 | nan |

and am trying to create additional revenue columns based upon their values of return, while adding together the values from rev1-rev5.

The resulting columns would look as follows:

| Date | NRev0 | NRev1 | NRev2 | NRev3 | NRev4 | NRev5 | NRev6 | NRev7 | NRev8 | NRev9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-1 | 100 | 500 | 100 | 200 | 300 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2020-2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 200 | 120 | 100 | 200 | 0 |
| 2020-3 | 0 | 0 | 100 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 100 | 0 | 200 |

Essentially, what I'm looking to do is to create a new variable "NRev," concatenated based upon the row value of "return." So if return1 = 4, for instance, NRev4 would equal the value of Rev1. The values of returns will change over time, but the number of return columns to revenue columns will always match. So theoretically, if there were a maximum value of 100 across all "Return" columns, the corresponding  "Revenue" column would create "NRev100", and be filled with the corresponding revenue value's index.

In SPSS, I am able to create the columns using this code, but is non pythonic, and the number of return and rev columns will increase over time, as well as return values:

```
if return1=0 NRev0= NRev0+Rev1.
if return1=1 NRev1= NRev1+Rev1.
if return1=2 NRev2= NRev2+Rev1.
if return1=3 NRev3= NRev3+Rev1.
if return1=4 NRev4= NRev4+Rev1.

if return2=0 NRev0= NRev0+Rev2.
if return2=1 NRev1= NRev1+Rev2.
if return2=2 NRev2= NRev2+Rev2.
if return2=3 NRev3= NRev3+Rev2.
if return2=4 NRev4= NRev4+Rev2.

if return3=0 NRev0= NRev0+Rev3.
if return3=1 NRev1= NRev1+Rev3.
if return3=2 NRev2= NRev2+Rev3.
if return3=3 NRev3= NRev3+Rev3.
if return3=4 NRev4= NRev4+Rev3.
```

Comment: Why does the last row have 200 in NRev8 and not NRev9?

Comment: I don't think this can be vectorised; I think you're going to have to iterate through the rows of the dataframe and then iterate through the columns manually.  In your final ('unpythonic') code you basically have an unrolled loop: now you need to roll that loop up.  But I could be wrong: there could be some neat way to do it.

Comment: @HenryEcker that was a mistake. i populated the dataset manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do some reshaping with [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) then [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) back to wide format. This allows us to align Return and Rev lines then convert the Return values to the new columns. Some cleanup with [`add_prefix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) and [`rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) can be done to polish the output:

```
new_df = (
    pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['Return', 'Rev'], i='Date', j='K')
        .dropna()
        .astype({'Return': int})
        .pivot_table(index='Date', columns='Return', values='Rev', fill_value=0)
        .add_prefix('NRev')
        .rename_axis(columns=None)
        .reset_index()
)
```

`new_df`:

```
     Date  NRev0  NRev1  NRev2  NRev3  NRev4  NRev5  NRev6  NRev7  NRev8  NRev9
0  2020-1    100    500    100    200    300      0      0      0      0      0
1  2020-2      0      0      0      0      0    200    120    100    200      0
2  2020-3      0      0    100      0      0      0      0    100      0    200
```

---

`wide_to_long` gives:

```
          Return    Rev
Date   K               
2020-1 1     0.0  100.0  # Corresponding Return index and Rev are in the same row
2020-2 1     5.0  200.0
2020-3 1     2.0  100.0
2020-1 2     1.0  500.0
2020-2 2     6.0  120.0
2020-3 2     3.0    0.0
2020-1 3     2.0  100.0
2020-2 3     7.0  100.0
2020-3 3     7.0  100.0
2020-1 4     3.0  200.0
2020-2 4     8.0  200.0
2020-3 4     9.0  200.0
2020-1 5     4.0  300.0
2020-2 5     NaN    NaN
2020-3 5     NaN    NaN  # These NaN are Not Needed
```

The Removing NaN step and returning Return to int

```
(pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['Return', 'Rev'], i='Date', j='K')
 .dropna()
 .astype({'Return': int}))
```

```
          Return    Rev
Date   K               
2020-1 1       0  100.0
2020-2 1       5  200.0
2020-3 1       2  100.0
2020-1 2       1  500.0
2020-2 2       6  120.0
2020-3 2       3    0.0
2020-1 3       2  100.0
2020-2 3       7  100.0
2020-3 3       7  100.0
2020-1 4       3  200.0
2020-2 4       8  200.0
2020-3 4       9  200.0
2020-1 5       4  300.0
```

Then this can easily be moved back to wide with a `pivot_table`:

```
(pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['Return', 'Rev'], i='Date', j='K')
 .dropna()
 .astype({'Return': int})
 .pivot_table(index='Date', columns='Return', values='Rev', fill_value=0))
```

```
Return    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
Date                                                    
2020-1  100  500  100  200  300    0    0    0    0    0
2020-2    0    0    0    0    0  200  120  100  200    0
2020-3    0    0  100    0    0    0    0  100    0  200
```

The rest is just cosmetic changes to the DataFrame.

---

If dates are duplicated `wide_to_long` cannot be used, but we can manually reshape the DataFrame to wide with [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) then [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
# Set Index Column
new_df = df.set_index('Date')
# Handle MultiIndex Manually
new_df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(
    new_df.columns.str.extract('(.*)(\d+)$')
)
# Stack then the rest is the same
new_df = (
    new_df.stack()
        .dropna()
        .astype({'Return': int})
        .pivot_table(index='Date', columns='Return', values='Rev',
                     fill_value=0, aggfunc='first')
        .add_prefix('NRev')
        .rename_axis(columns=None)
        .reset_index()
)
```

Sample DF with duplicate dates:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2020-1', '2020-2', '2020-2'],
                   'Return1': [0, 5, 0],
                   'Return2': [1, 6, 1],
                   'Return3': [2, 7, 2],
                   'Return4': [3, 8, 3],
                   'Return5': [4.0, nan, 4.0],
                   'Rev1': [100, 200, 100],
                   'Rev2': [500, 120, 0],
                   'Rev3': [100, 100, 100],
                   'Rev4': [200, 200, 200],
                   'Rev5': [300.0, nan, nan]})
```

`df`

```
     Date  Return1  Return2  Return3  Return4  Return5  Rev1  Rev2  Rev3  Rev4   Rev5
0  2020-1        0        1        2        3      4.0   100   500   100   200  300.0
1  2020-2        5        6        7        8      NaN   200   120   100   200    NaN
2  2020-2        0        1        2        3      4.0   100     0   100   200    NaN
```

`new_df`

```
     Date  NRev0  NRev1  NRev2  NRev3  NRev4  NRev5  NRev6  NRev7  NRev8
0  2020-1    100    500    100    200    300      0      0      0      0
1  2020-2    100      0    100    200      0    200    120    100    200
```

Comment: neat!  I stand corrected.

Comment: You were correct that this is still a fairly expensive operation and may take some time and memory.

Comment: didn't know pandas had a `pivot_table` though.  that's the first *good* reason I've seen to use it...

Comment: I get an error on the first part running this: ValueError: the id variables need to uniquely identify each row. In the original data, there are a variable number of duplicate return dates.

Comment: Well Then this approach is not going to work. How do you want to handle collisions?

Comment: Henry - there equal number of "Date" columns to returns and revenue columns as well. the date referenced in the example data in this post is the date that will eventually be aggregated on to sum counts of NRev1-Nrev#.

Comment: Check the last code snippet which manually does the wide_to_long operations and can handle duplicate dates.

Comment: Thanks. this is getting closer to where i need to be. the only issue is the resulting values for revenue are off. i'll keep investigating.

Comment: Just figured it out. What i need was to set the index as "Date" and "Customer ID" which aren't in the posted, then using aggfunc="sum." Thanks for this!